# How to change "setState()" when using GetX in Flutter?

Tags: state, setstate, flutter-getx, obs

I have a login screen code like below that has a text button that changes the state of the Login button to Signup or reverse, and want to rewrite it to use `GetX` library. But I don't know how?

```
    enum AuthMode { Signup, Login }
    
    class AuthenticationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const AuthenticationScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      AuthMode _authMode = AuthMode.Login;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
    
        void _switchAuthMode() {
          if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
             setState(() {
            _authMode = AuthMode.Signup;
=             });
            _controller!.forward();
          } else {
             setState(() {
            _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
             });
            _controller!.reverse();
          }
        }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
,
              TextButton(
                child: Text(
                    '${_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'SIGNUP' : 'LOGIN'} '),
                onPressed: _switchAuthMode,
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4),
                  tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

I tried some changes like transferring `Authmode` to the `auth_controller` file that extends `GetxController` and add `obs` after `AuthMode _authMode = AuthMode.Login;` and try to use `obx(()=>)` inside the `_switchAuthMode()` but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
final authMode= Rx<AuthMode>(AuthMode.Login);
```

And then on your `switchAuthMode` method:

```
 authMode.value = AuthMode.Signup; // without setState
```

And finally, wrap the `Text` widget with `Obx`:

```
 Obx(()=> Text('${authMode.value == AuthMode.Login ? 'SIGNUP' : 'LOGIN'} ')
```

And you can actually make your widget a StatelessWidget.